# Fan doesn't work on an Acer Aspire 5315

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, fan, bios

I have recently installed lubuntu 11.10 on my old laptop (acer aspire 5315 celeron) and observed that fan is not working properly on lubuntu side.I find it strange that it is working perfectly under window vista.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem got solved by updating the BIOS

Comment: Could you post the BIOS model/version for question completeness ?

Answer (score 0):

Many Acer laptops need *acerhdf* in order to control the speed fan correctly. Without acerhdf a Acer 1810TZ makes a lot of noise (running Ubuntu and connected to power). Unfortunately your laptopt doesn't seem to be officially supported (your modell is not listed in the part of the source code, see code block below). You can still force to run it, but this is not a good idea if you don't know if this would damage your hardware. Run `dmesg|grep acer` to check if there were any messages from acerhdf (it should be included in newer kernels).

```
/* Register addresses and values for different BIOS versions */
static const struct bios_settings_t bios_tbl[] = {
    /* AOA110 */
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3109", 0x55, 0x58, {0x1f, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3114", 0x55, 0x58, {0x1f, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3301", 0x55, 0x58, {0xaf, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3304", 0x55, 0x58, {0xaf, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3305", 0x55, 0x58, {0xaf, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3307", 0x55, 0x58, {0xaf, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3308", 0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3309", 0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA110", "v0.3310", 0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    /* AOA150 */
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3114", 0x55, 0x58, {0x1f, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3301", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3304", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3305", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3307", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3308", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3309", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AOA150", "v0.3310", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    /* Acer 1410 */
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3108", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3113", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3115", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3117", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3119", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v0.3120", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v1.3204", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v1.3303", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v1.3308", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v1.3310", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1410", "v1.3314", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    /* Acer 1810xx */
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3108", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3108", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3113", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3113", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3115", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3115", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3117", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3117", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3119", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3119", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v0.3120", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v0.3120", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v1.3204", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v1.3204", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v1.3303", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v1.3303", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v1.3308", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v1.3308", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v1.3310", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v1.3310", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810TZ", "v1.3314", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1810T",  "v1.3314", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    /* Acer 531 */
    {"Acer", "AO531h", "v0.3201", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Acer", "AO531h", "v0.3304", 0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    /* Acer 751 */
    {"Acer", "AO751h", "V0.3212", 0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    /* Acer 1825 */
    {"Acer", "Aspire 1825PTZ", "V1.3118", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    /* Gateway */
    {"Gateway", "AOA110", "v0.3103",  0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    {"Gateway", "AOA150", "v0.3103",  0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Gateway", "LT31",   "v1.3103",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Gateway", "LT31",   "v1.3201",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Gateway", "LT31",   "v1.3302",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Gateway", "LT31",   "v1.3303t", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    /* Packard Bell */
    {"Packard Bell", "DOA150", "v0.3104",  0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOA150", "v0.3105",  0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "AOA110", "v0.3105",  0x55, 0x58, {0x21, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "AOA150", "v0.3105",  0x55, 0x58, {0x20, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v1.3303",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3120",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3108",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3113",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3115",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3117",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v0.3119",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMU",  "v1.3204",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMA",  "v1.3201",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMA",  "v1.3302",  0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    {"Packard Bell", "DOTMA",  "v1.3303t", 0x55, 0x58, {0x9e, 0x00} },
    /* pewpew-terminator */
    {"", "", "", 0, 0, {0, 0} }
};
```

Comment: the problem got solved by updating the **BIOS**

Comment: Ah yes, that's alsa always I good hint I didn't think of. If you find a solution on your own, the proper way to mark the question as answered is to write your solution in an answer and to mark it as accepted!